# How to time the duration of an operation with subsecond accuracy?

Tags: time, rust, duration

I want to find the elapsed time of an OpenGL frame. I was using

```
self.start.elapsed().subsec_nanos(); // self.start is a std::time::Instant
```

and it worked fine on my laptop. When I put the code on a Raspberry Pi it wouldn't compile because `subsec_nanos()` and `from_nanos()` are unstable. I tried micros and millis but they seem to be unstable too. I've been googling this for an hour now and can't find any other way of getting elapsed time less than a second. Have I missed something obvious?

On my laptop I am running cargo 1.27.0 and rustc 1.27.0. On the RPi they are
cargo 0.26.0 and rustc 1.25.0. I tried `rustup update` but got `stable-armf7...update failed`

I get `error[E0658] use of unstable library feature 'duration_extras'... (see #46507)`
or `'duration_from_micros'... (see #44400)`

I don't want to use nightly or inflict complicated installation requirements on anyone trying the code. I want them to be able to use the standard vanilla rustup install process.

Comment: [`Duration::subec_nanos`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.3.0/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.subsec_nanos) has been stable since 1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

While you are stuck on an old Rust version, you could try the popular [time](https://crates.io/crates/time) library for date-time calculation.

Comment: While this (maybe) answers the question, showing an example that demonstrates how to get subsecond duration would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with upgrading and installing the current version on Raspberry Pi see:

- [rustup issue #1403](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1403)
- [rustup issue #1410](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1410)
- [Rust issue #49462](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49462)

After I looked at the full error messages, I noticed that there are two errors:

1. initially was due to using `from_nanos()` to set the start time for each frame.
2. When I switched to using micros or millis I got a different error due to `subsec_micros()` or `subsec_millis()`

As [@DK says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217774/how-to-find-sub-second-duration-in-rust#comment89420894_51217774), `subsec_nanos()` is stable in 1.25.0 and the eventual solution was to use that along with `Duration::new()`

```
let mut del = self.start.elapsed().subsec_nanos();
if del < self.target_frame_tm {
    let delay = Duration::new(0, (self.target_frame_tm - del) as u32);
    sleep(delay);
    del = self.target_frame_tm;
}
```